# Organize dynamically sized panels in a table format (Java SWING)

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I've been trying to use a GridBagLayout to organize a bunch of panels (containing a bunch of labels which alter the size of the panel, mostly vertically). The major reason why i chose this is because the panel sizes can vary quite different, and I would like the panels to scale when the frame size is changed.

I keep coming across problems ranging from different sized panels (checking via borders on panels), weird sizing issues, cant get the panels to stick to each other vertically (massive space inbetween panels).

Gridbag seemed like the best option but it seems like its becoming a bigger pain than i imagined. What other options provide proper scaling when altering the frame size?

Comment: 1) look into use of MigLayout, a 3rd party layout manager that you will have to download. 2) or if you want our help to help you to optimize GridBagLayout or any other layouts, come back here with code, preferably a [mcve], and with images of your desired and observed GUI's.

Comment: Edit - Found download links, but not sure which one to download, so many versions.

Answer (score 3):

I have become a fan of [what @SplungeBob showed me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21030105/2737933) a long time ago. The code snippet below gives you an idea of what it takes to accomplish the GUI shown below it.

```
    frame.add(menu,             new GBConstraints( 0, 0).spanX(32).fill(HORIZONTAL));
    frame.add(new JLabel("Available letters"), 
                                new GBConstraints( 0, 1).insets( 2, 2, 0, 2));
    frame.add(new JLabel("Play by play..."), 
                                new GBConstraints( 2, 1).insets( 0, 5, 0, 0));
    frame.add(pnlPlays,         new GBConstraints( 2, 1).insets(10, 0, 0, 0).spanY(14).anchor(WEST).fill(BOTH));//.ipad(0,0));

    frame.add(pnlAvail,         new GBConstraints( 0, 2).insets(0, 5, 5, 5));
    frame.add(pnlLegend,        new GBConstraints( 1, 2)                    .spanY(14)              .fill(BOTH));
    frame.add(pnlBonuses,       new GBConstraints( 0, 3).insets(0, 100, 0, 0));
    frame.add(pnlSBBonuses,     new GBConstraints( 0, 3).insets(0, 125, 0, 0));
    frame.add(gamePanel,        new GBConstraints( 0, 5).insets(0, 50, 0, 0));
    frame.add(pnlTheScore,      new GBConstraints( 0, 5)                                .anchor(EAST));
    btnDebug.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1, 1));
    frame.add(btnDebug,         new GBConstraints( 0, 0)                                .anchor(WEST));

    frame.add(btnNextReplayStep,new GBConstraints( 0, 6).insets(0,310, 0, 0)            .anchor(CENTER));
              btnNextReplayStep.setVisible(false);
    frame.add(new JLabel("User letters"),
                                new GBConstraints( 0, 6).insets(0,240, 30, 0));
    frame.add(btnCopyUser,      new GBConstraints( 0, 6).insets(0,310,0,0)              .anchor(CENTER));

    frame.add(btnCopyAllLetters,new GBConstraints( 0, 6)                                .anchor(EAST));
    frame.add(pnlNotes,         new GBConstraints( 0, 6).insets(25,10,10, 10).spanY(  2).anchor(WEST));
    frame.add(btnClearMnemHi,   new GBConstraints( 0, 7).insets(0,430, 0, 0));
    frame.add(btnClearBorders,  new GBConstraints( 0, 7).insets(0,530, 0, 0));
```

[image]

I won't lie; it can still be a major task, but with careful planning with an actual grid marked off in vertical and horizontal lines to show, e.g., how many columns a field must `span`, it's worth a try. And chances are excellent that what @Hovercraft suggests is even better.

(I haven't mastered it, it seems as the weird `insets` values seem to indicate. But it's a nice-looking reliable GUI.)

**EDIT**

Here's code for how two of the `JPanel` objects were created prior to executing the code above. One also uses `GridBagLayout`; other doesn't. Just whatever works easiest and best.

```
  private void makePlays(){  
    pnlPlays = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    pnlPlays.setSize(500,300);
    pnlPlays.add(scrPlays, new GBConstraints(0,1).span(40, 62)
                                                 .fill(BOTH).ipad(100, 50));
    scrPlays.setEnabled(false);
  }

  private void makeScoremasterBonuses(){
    BonusBackgroundColors c;
    BonusBackgroundColors all   [] = BonusBackgroundColors.values();
    String labels[] = new String[all.length];
    String abbrs [] = new String[all.length];

    JButton but;
    pnlBonuses = new JPanel();
    pnlBonuses.add(new JLabel("Legend:"));

    for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
      labels[i] = all[i].name().replace("_", " ").toLowerCase();
      abbrs [i] = Utilities.abbreviate(all[i].name());
      c = BonusBackgroundColors.values()[i];
      but = new JButton(abbrs[i]);
      but.setToolTipText(labels[i]);
      but.setBackground(c.background(c));
      but.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
      but.setActionCommand("" + i);
      but.addActionListener(this);
      pnlBonuses.add(but);
    }
  }
```